# how to check the UIAlertview existence on some operation in iPhone UIautomation java script

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, ios5, ios-ui-automation

I am writing a java script to do `UIAutomation` of an iPhone application.
I want to check 2 scenarios at a button hit event:

1. to check whether it is showing a alert view on the hit of this button.
2. if there is a alertview then what is the alert message.

Can anyone let me know that ho to check this scenario.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can make something like this :

```
... // previous code, assuming btn exists
var alertCalled = null;
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
  UIALogger.logMessage("alertShown : " + alert.name());
  alertCalled = {};
  alertCalled.title = alert.name();
  var messageText = alert.staticTexts()[1]; // 0 is title
  if( messageText )
  {
    alertCalled.message = messageText.name();
  }
  return false;// default alert action
}
btn.tap();
this.target.delay(1); // let time to make alert appear
if( alertCalled == null )
{
   UIALogger.logFail('alert not shown');
}
```